# Get xml attribute values as string[]

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

My xml file has something like this:
`...

<Keyword name = "if" />

<Keyword name = "else" />

<Keyword name = "is" />

...`
So how can I recursively get all of the values of the `name` attribute and add them to a `List<string>` or `string[]`. Maybe a foreach loop?

---

I followed codemeit's and I keep getting an error:`Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` My xml file is
`<KeyWords>`
`...`
`<KeyWord name = "if" />`
`...`
`</KeyWord>`

---

New problem `The '\' character, hexadecimal value 0x5C, cannot be included in a name.` but the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume let variable testXml is equal to the follow xml string

```
<Keywords>
 <Keyword name = "if" />
 <Keyword name = "else" />
 <Keyword name = "is" />
</Keywords>
```

Use XElement and LINQ to extract the name attribute values

```
var myXml = XElement.Parse(testXml );
var myArray = myXml.Elements().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName.Equals("Keyword"))
                    .Select(n => n.Attribute("name").Value)
                    .ToArray();
```

myArray will contain {"if", "else", "is"}

UPDATE

Thanks to @SLaks comment, we could actually just do

```
var myArray = myXml.Elements("Keyword").Attributes("name").Select(n => n.Value);
```

Comment: You should call `myXml.Elements("Keyword")`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist(VS.80).aspx) class. You need to pass proper XPATH to fetch the values and iterate through the list.