# How do Extract information from a very generic xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmlreader

My xml document is as follows (but much larger and not anything to do with date of birth info).  It is produced by a method and I want to access information from it.

I would like to look up a "Name" like John or Hannah and get DOB from the next line and perhaps put them into a `Dictionary<string,string>` for later look-up.

The document is ALWAYS in this form and Names are unique.  I only need the first section name = "DOBs".

```
<info>
  <section name="DOBs">
   <table>
    <headers>
      <cell value="Name" />
      <cell value="DOB" />
    </headers>
    <row>
      <cell value="John" />
      <cell value="121245" />
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell value="Hannah" />
      <cell value="050595" />
    </row>
   </table>
  </section>
  <section name="notDOBs">
   <table>
    <headers>
      <cell value="Name" />
      <cell value="other info" />
    </headers>
    <row>
      <cell value="Hannah" />
      <cell value="blue" />
    </row>
    ....
    </table>
  </section>
</info>
```

What have I tried? - to be honest, not a lot as I'm confused about xml in general.  I've looked at a few SO entries: [Xml Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591135/extract-contents-from-xml-file),[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093347/how-can-i-extract-an-xml-block-from-an-xml-document) and [How to use XMLreader to read this xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381720/how-to-use-xmlreader-to-read-this-xml).  I also looked at [csharp-examples.net](http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/) which looked good but I kept getting errors about "not leading to node set".

I got excited when I found this: [get xml attribut values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035991/get-xml-attribute-values-as-string) but no joy, it doesn't seem to find them only the  ones.

```
var myXml = XElement.Load(_myPath).Elements();
var myArray = myXml.Elements("cell").Attributes("value").Select(n => n.Value);
```

I know I have a LOT more work to do but sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and ask ... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml")
            .Descendants("section")
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("DOBs"))
            .Descendants("row")
            .Descendants("cell")
            .Attributes("value").ToList();

var dic = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count/2)
    .ToDictionary(i => list[2*i], i => list[2*i + 1]);
```

Comment: can I just ask how that would change if I had another section that I didn't care too much about called '<section name="notDOBs">...</section>' (sorry, I forgot about that - it only showed up when your piece of code worked so well!)

Comment: @Sisyphus: what do you mean, could you update your question on this?

Comment: Thanks @Cuong - have made the edit to include the second <section> part that I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

[Sort XML nodes alphabetically on attribute name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943635/sort-xml-nodes-alphabetically-on-attribute-name/12943861#12943861)

Check the above sample

in navigator try to use

```
      .MoveFirstChild() method
      .MoveNext() method
      .MoveToFirstAttribute() method
      .MoveToNextAttribute() method
      .Name property
      .Value property
```

do not forget to check if the current one is null or not

Comment: Thanks for the link, it gave me this ... 'myXml.Descendants("cell")' ... which I think may help dig down into the xml docuemnt - I was looking at the top level I think.